# A way to forcefully close modal QFileDialog on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I have a Qt application which at some point calls `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName`. However, at any point my application can get an event which will make this file dialog irrelevant, so I want to forcefully close it.

This is my way of trying to close this dialog:

```
QWidget *modalWidget = QApplication::activeModalWidget();
if (modalWidget)
    modalWidget->close();
```

This works on Windows, but I get strange behavior on Mac. Instead of closing, it hides the dialog instead. Execution never leaves `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName` call and since it's a modal dialog, underlying app becomes permanently frozen.

Comment: You may need to avoid calling QFileDialog::getOpenFileName() and instead manually create a QFileDialog object and show() it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of closure, I ended up closing the dialog by calling native [`[NSApp abortModal]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428753-abortmodal?language=objc).

Note that this workaround might not be needed if this issue was fixed in the recent Qt releases (haven't checked since Qt 5.8).